# Use multiple variables in a loop

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, variables

I'm trying to check if five numbers are odd or even. I want to use a for-loop that iterates 5 times and uses a for loop that checks if the number is odd or even.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a ,b ,c ,d ,e;

    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b ,&c ,&d ,&e);

    int count = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        
        if(num % 2 == 0) //num should be a then b then c etc.

        printf("even");

        else

        printf("odd");
    }

}
```

I cant find any information about swapping/switching variables inside a loop/statment. If anyone has an answer or where to find the information i will be forever grateful!

Thanks in advance!
//Noob programmer

Comment: You don't need separate variable, or arrays even, just a single variable which holds the current input. Then put the reading of the input *in the loop itself*.

Comment: Seems like i was googling the wrong question, when using arrays i got millions of examples/answers! Thanks!

Comment: If you're an absolute beginner in C and programming, then I really recommend that you invest in some beginners books (or maybe even take a few classes) to learn. While it's easy to find tutorials and examples all over the Internet, not many are good, and some could even contain false or wrong information. Once you have the basics nailed down, it will be easier to spot bad or wrong examples or tutorials.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you do not want to learn the arrays there is a hardcore way of doing it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0: 
            num = a;
            break;
        case 1: 
            num = b;
            break;

        /* etc etc etc */
    }
}
```

Comment: Now try that with 10 numbers, or 20, etc. ;)

Comment: As I wrote it is a hardcore way :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of scanf-ing into distinct variables (a, b, etc.), perhaps you can [scanf into an array of integers](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/C/0140__Array/Usescanftoreaddataintoarray.htm).

Then you can use indexing of the array.

```
int num = numbers[i];
```

Within the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, this can be solved with only a single variable and without arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned const count = 5;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        fflush(stdout);  // To make sure the output is printed

        int number;
        scanf("%d", &number); // Note: Doesn't handle errors

        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("The number %d is even\n", number);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The number %d is odd\n", number);
        }
    }
}
```